# Reclassification and Con(0 not working arcpy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, error-999999, reclassify, con

I have a raster that has three pixel values=0,1,2. I want all pixels of value 2 to be 1. The raster is in tif format, 32 bit signed type. Below is my arcpy script-

```
inRaster1="path address/input.tif"

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#Reclassifying 
outReclass=Reclassify(inRaster1, "Value", RemapValue([[0,0],[1,1],[2,1]]))
print "Reclassification is complete"

outReclass.save("address path/output.tif")
print "Saved. Check"

arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

However, I get the 9999 Error and I do not know how to fix it! So instead, I used the Con tool as below and saved the output.

```
outCon = Con(inRaster1==2, 1, inRaster1)
print "Reclassification is complete"
```

BUt the pixel values do no change i.e. the saved raster still has pixel values=0,1,2 instead of 0 & 1. And this was completed with no errors.
I then modified the code line to

```
outCon=Con(inRaster1>1,1,inRaster1)
```

And this time all values were reclassified to 1 i.e. even the pixels with value 0.

What is going wrong with the Reclassify() and why is Con() not reclassifying 2.How do i reclassify pixel value=2 to 1

Comment: In= arcpy.Raster(path) and try again.

Comment: Yes this worked! Thank you @FelixIP. But I do not understand the logic.Could you explain?

Comment: ArcGIS is inconsistent with it. Do any raster calculation, go to results window and copy as python snippet. You'll see Raster() around raster name in mxd. I guess there it is something to do  with a difference between raster name and raster object.